# How can i open, read, close, update, reopen and read a file without refreshing in php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to make a chat application using html and php.

I am writing a .txt file with the whole chat in it and want to read it every five seconds without refreshing my page. I tried to use a loop in javascript, but it dont refreshes the file after open it again.

```
function readChat(){
      clearArea();
    <?php

        if ($file = fopen("chat.txt", "r")) {
          while(!feof($file)) {
            $line = trim(fgets($file));
            if($line !== " "){
              $arr = explode(":", $line, 2);
              $name = $arr[0];
              $string = $arr[1];
              $string = str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), '', $string);


              if($name === $_COOKIE["username"] && $string !== "" && $string !== " " && $string !== "\n"){
                echo "selfMessage(\"".$string."\");";
              }else if($line !== "" && $line !== " " && $line !== "\n" && $string !== "" && $string !== " " && $string !== "\n"){
                echo "otherMessage(\"".$string."\", \"".$name."\");";
              }
            }
          }
          fclose($file);
        }



    ?>
    }

      window.setInterval(function() {
        readChat();
      }, 5000);
```

This is what i tried so far.

Comment: I think you need Ajax to call another php script. That php script is just going to open an read or open and write (what you need)and you can call it asynchronously. Chech this [AJAX PHP W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_php.asp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having is due to mixing PHP and Javascript code.

First you should know that the PHP code executes on the server which generates the page content that will be sent to the client (web browser). Then that web browser executes the Javascript code contained in the page content it receives.

Can you see already why the chat isn't updating?

Your PHP function executes just once, when the page is requested, and inserts the chat messages into the body of the `readChat()` function. When the browser receives the web page data that contains `readChat()` it just sees the chat messages as if they were hard-coded into the function!

For Example, the following PHP script:

```php
function someJSFunc() {
    <?php
        $now = date('m/d/Y H:i:s', time());
        echo "var now = '$now';";
    ?>
    console.log(now);
}
```

Results in the following function being sent to the client:

```
function someJSFunc() {
    var now = '6/4/2019 16:39:18';
    console.log(now);
}
```

No matter how many times the client calls `someJSFunc()` it will always output the same date and time because that was the time that the PHP function executed.

Sometimes mixing PHP and Javascript this way can be very useful, but to accomplish what you are looking for you are going to need to use AJAX requests.

An AJAX request can be accomplished easily using [JQuery](https://jquery.com/). All you need to do is add another `<script>` tag to your page header to include the JQuery script. Further instructions on setting up JQuery can be found on their website.

Next you have to fix your `readChat()` function. Instead of using PHP in that function, just use javascript and use JQuery to perform a GET request.

```javascript
function readChat() {
    clearArea();
    $.get("getchat.php", function(data) {
        // inside this function data will contain whatever your PHP script echos
        $('#chat').html(data);    // for example, replacing a div with id="chat" with the data received from getchat.php
    });
    window.setInterval(function() { readChat(); }, 5000);  // I would personally move this outside of readChat() so that it is only called once...
}
```

This function will load `getchat.php` every time the browser calls `readChat()`, and set up an interval to call `readChat()` every 5 seconds. The function inside `$.get()` is where you can use the data received from `getchat.php`. It is usually just a string that you can insert into your chat area or div, but it depends on how you make the `getchat.php` script work.

Lastly you just make a new PHP script called `getchat.php` that will read the chat file and echo it in the format that you would like to see added to the page.

Comment: The problem is that i don't understand how to use JQuere or AJAX.

Comment: @kevwpl I have updated this answer to better explain how to use JQuery and make AJAX requests.